# How to keep touchpad deactivated when I'm typing?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I used the command `syndaemon -i 1 -d` to keep my touchpad deactivated when I type. But whenever I put my laptop to sleep and then turn it on again, somehow the touchpad gets reactivated. How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you want it to be persistent over reboots?

Comment: yes, that's what I want